# Redux: Global configuration for reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a reducer, that tracks a some kind of date in my application state. By default it's a current date, acquired through moment.js library.

```js
const selectedDateReducer = (state = moment(), action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_DATE':
        return action.date;
    default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

That works well, but now I want all dates to be in specific locale:

```js
const selectedDateReducer = (state = moment().locale(globalLocale), action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_DATE':
        return action.date;
    default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

I also need the same locale in my React component, so I pass it like:

```jsx
<Component locale={globalLocale}></Component>
```

and don't want to hard code it.

Global variables also don't work well, since it's hard to redefine them during tests.

If it wasn't a part of state initiation, I could just pass it as a part of some action, but I need `globalLocale` in my reducer initialization code.

Perhaps, in this particular situaution I could move locale logic to some other place, but I'm mostly interested in some kind of general pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You just make a module out of it.

```
export const globalLocale = 'en';
```

You can then use it from anywhere you need it by just importing it. Alternatively,  you can make it a function so you can change it at any time. However, this makes it state, so it should then be put inside Redux. The only exception to that might be if you set it once at initialization time as that still makes it a constant for the duration of the lifetime of the app.

```
let currentLocale = 'en';
export const globalLocale = () => currentLocale;
export const setGlobalLocale = newLocale => currentLocale = newLocale;
```

Now, because it's a module, it'll really be global. This means that if you use server-side React, all rendering the server does will be with the same locale. The solution there is to just use Redux.

As a side note: time is an entity that is separate from the way humans label it. It exists for all of us simultaneously. "Now" is the same for you and I and anyone and anything on earth or elsewhere.

This means that setting a locale on a date is not necessarily a good idea. It's better to store a generic date.

Also, state is normally just a plain object. A `moment` instance doesn't necessarily belong in the Redux state.

What would make most sense to me is to store either a `Date` (which is serializable with `JSON.stringify` or a Unix timestamp (`(new Date ()).getTime()`) along with the current locale, which will be app-global because the app only had one canonical Redux state.

Then you make a helper function which takes the date and locale and formats the date according to the current locale, with the help of `moment`, of course, and use this function in your components or in your `mapStateToProps`.